# Adding custom code to Qt UIC generated file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio with Qt Plugin. In order to design my UI, I use the Qt Designer tool to directly get the .ui file from which the Qt UIC generated the .h file.

Now the Qt designer has certain drawbacks due to which now I want to add my custom code in order to polish the UI further. One would add this directly to the .h file generated by the Qt UIC but then everytime I recompile, the changes are lost.

How should I go about adding my own code to the Qt UIC generated .h file ?

Comment: You add this code to the QWidget that composes or inherits the generated ui object.

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed, it's a bad idea to edit the generated .h file which will be overwritten when recompiling. One place to add polishing code is in the constructor of the class that composes the generated UI object. For example:

```
// MainWindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
  ui.setupUi(this);

  // Additional polish      
  ui.textEdit->setText("Hello !");
}

// MainWindow.h
#include "ui_MainWindow.h" // the generated UI header

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:  
  Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
};
```